# Getting lambda arn from an external module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I'm using this [module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest). Specifically, my lambda looks like this:

```
module "lambda_function_existing_package_s3" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"

  function_name = "lambda"
  description   = "lambda"
  lambda_role    = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  runtime = "python3.8"
  timeout = 30

  create_package      = false
  
  s3_existing_package = {
    bucket = var.bucket_id
    key    = "bucket/location"
  }

  vpc_subnet_ids         = [var.subnet1, var.subnet2]
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.allow_egress.id]
  attach_network_policy = true

  environment_variables = {
    1 = "1",
    2 = "2"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to export the arn of this lambda as SSM, like this:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "lambda" {
  name  = "/lambda/arn"
  type  = "String"
  value = module.lambda_function_existing_package_s3.this.arn
}
```

This is my latest attempt, which throws an error, saying that
`this object doesn't have attribute "this"`, even though the docs mention it. I have also tried:

`value = module.lambda_function_existing_package_s3.arn`, and

`value = aws_lambda_function.this.arn`

None of it works, and I'm not sure why. I've managed to deploy the lambda without errors when I commented out the SSM part, and this is what the output looks like:

```
name: this  
provider: hashicorp/aws
type: aws_lambda_function   
module: lambda_function_existing_package_s3
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [module outputs documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest?tab=outputs), the namespace for the Lambda function ARN value would be `module.<declared name>.lambda_function_arn`.

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "lambda" {
  name  = "/lambda/arn"
  type  = "String"
  value = module.lambda_function_existing_package_s3.lambda_function_arn
}
```